# QT creator and xcode static compilation

Tags: c++, xcode, qt, visual-studio-2013

I want to create a plug-in in Photoshop, I wanted it to be cross platformed. I have used he QT creator and created the pro file for the same. I have used the QT creator and VS2013 compiler for the windows and able run the plug-in in Photoshop successfully.

Output file of the projects is a Dll in windows, I wanted it's dependency to be linked statically so user need to just use the output file only. I have used the following flags and able to link the dependency statically in windows

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG += /MTd
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += /MT

Now I have used the same pro file in mac and able to compile the code in mac(using clang compiler - Xcode), but it produce the "dylib", I am very new to the mac system so is it as same as the dll in windows?

What are the changes I have to make to link the dependency statically in mac?

Answer (score 0):

.dylib is the analog of .dll in Windows. In fact it is an old BSD/Linux .so with different suffix.

For Photoshop under OS X you probably need an application bundle instead of plain shared library (Not sure, please read Photoshop SDK).

Read here how to create bundles with qmake: https://forum.qt.io/topic/1102/how-to-create-a-bundle-library-mh_bundle-with-qmake-on-mac-os-x

Comment: PS. A bundle is a special folder structure with actual library as well as resources located at predefined places recognized by OS X.